# Mostrar mensagem sucesso/erro depois do postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Tenho as seguintes funções na minha página, quando chamo elas via javascript, funcionam perfeitamente:

```
function msgSucesso(msg) {
    toastr.success(msg);
}

function msgErro(msg) {
    toastr.error(msg);
}
```

Daí, tenho um botão na minha página aspx que chama um evento do servidor:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSalvar" runat="server" OnClick="btnSalvar_Click" Text="Salvar" />
```

No cobehind:

```
protected void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // código para salvar
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // erro
    }
}
```

Gostaria de chamar as funções `msgSucesso` ou `msgErro` quando tudo der certo ou quando der erro, respectivamente, quando executar o evento do servidor. Como fazer isso? Sei que é fácil, mas estou acostumado com ASP.NET MVC que é bem diferente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o método `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`:

```
protected void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // código para salvar
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "sucesso", "msgSucesso('Sucesso ao salvar')", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // erro
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "sucesso", "msgErro('Erro ao salvar')", true);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, funcionou. Obrigado.